# Ghidra: undefined4 to bytearray

Tags: decompilation, ghidra, decompiler, struct

I am trying to reverse a `c++` program and make the decompiler represent a byte-array in a single line.
The `c++` code contains the following line:

```
BYTE fileArray[139] = {0x50, 0x51....}
```

Ghidra decompiles this to:

```
  undefined4 local_98;
  undefined4 local_94;
  undefined4 local_90;

  local_98 = 0x4035150;
  local_94 = 0x14;
  local_90 = 0x89630000;
...
```

I managed to set the data type to `byte[139]` expecting it to result in a single line representing the byte-array but instead I got the following result:

```
  byte local_98 [139];
  
  local_98[0] = 0x50;
  local_98[1] = 0x51;
  local_98[2] = 3;
...
```

Is it possible to display a byte-array (or even a char array) in a single line in Ghidra?
And if not, is there a reason why?

Comment: if the underlying disassembly assignement is in dword sized ptr there is no way the decompiler can infer a byte sized assignemnt  if the original code was byte foo[xx] = {...} compiler will normally make it dword blah [xx/4] = { group of 4 bytes per assignement .... }

Comment: Alright, and is it possible to format it yourself in Ghidra? I don't mind the manual work but with this formatting its hard to keep overview (for me atleast)

Comment: Sorry i dont know i simply set the data-type rename the xxx_nn to myfoo confirm by scrolling if there are 139 myfoo[index]   and simply ignore the long display